# Calculating different probability functions based on given values

Tags: probability

I know that

$$P(A) = 0.12$$
$$P(B|A) = 0.60$$
$$P(B|\overline A) = 0.50$$

and i need to calculate

$$P(A \cap B)$$
$$P(B)$$
$$P(A \cup B)$$
$$P(A|B)$$
$$P(A|\overline B)$$
$$P(\overline A\setminus B)$$

I calculated that

$$P(A \cap B)=0.07$$
$$P(B)=0.60$$
$$P(A \cup B)=0.65$$
$$P(A|B)=0.12$$
$$P(A|\overline B)=0.18$$
$$P(\overline A\setminus B)=0.35$$

I have focused these to two numbers (0.XX) but am i doing something wrong as my answers are not correct?

Comment: Your $P(B)$ is the first incorrect one. Could you let us in on your thought process behind that. Also, did you draw a Venn diagram?

Answer (score 1):

$1.~$ $p(A \cap B) = p(B/A)p(A)= 0.6*0.12=0.072$

$2.~$ $p(B)$

$p(B/A^{'})= \frac{p(B \cap A^{'})}{p(A^{'})} = \frac{p(B)-p(B \cap A)}{1-p(A)} \rightarrow p(B)= 0.5*(1-0.12)+(0.072)=0.512$

$3.~$ $p(A\cup B) = p(A)+p(B)-p(A \cap B)= 0.12+ 0.512 - 0.072 = 0.56$

$4.~ p(A/B)= \frac{p(A \cap B)}{p(B)}= \frac{0.072}{0.512}= 0.140625$

$5.~$ $p(A/ B^{'})= \frac{p(A\cap B^{'})}{p(B^{'})}= \frac{p(A)- p(A\cap B)}{1-p(B)}= \frac{0.12-0.072}{1-0.512}=0.09836 $

$6.~$ $p(A^{'}/ B)= \frac{p(A^{'}\cap B)}{p(B)}= \frac{p(B)- p(A\cap B)}{p(B)}= \frac{0.512-0.072}{0.512}= 0.859375 $

or in another simple way $p(A^{'}/ B) = 1- p(A/ B) = 1- 0.140625 $

Comment: This is not to discourage you: I think it would be better to engage with the principles of understanding and breaking down the problems rather than to give a full solution.

Comment: @String I am totally agree with you _if he didn't try_! I wrote a full detailed solution because I saw that he _tried_ to solve the exercise. I think he can now see where is the problem exactly while following the steps. Any way your message is well received and I will take it into consideration next time, thanks for the advice.

Comment: Thank you, I think we are largely in agreement. The main potential drawback I see here is that the OP might not be at the point of just reading your solution and immediately understanding their mistakes. There could be a deeper misunderstanding at play that could be resolved through a bit of two-way-dialogue. If so, resolving that would serve a greater end goal, IMO.